How to make the Java JAR file of extra_module of OpenCv and merge it with base OpenCv module
(pls tell me , i  have project due in 2weeks - which needs this face classes in my project.)
So i was trying to add JAVA face_module from opencv_contrib , using cmake & visual studio -  did everything to add the extra modules path . i added proper configure and generated it .
But there is no JAR file it that new directory.
I have tried to change the cmakelist.txt to java , but i dont know what do you mean by Compiling - means where do i have to compile it.
(i have read all other question - but i dont know how to do it ,please provide understandable steps.
I want anyone to provide me how to do it or tell me in step to do it - and i really dont know what to compile and where, please i need this quickly for my face_recognition project.
(everything i see is for python , they are pip install) but i am using Java - with NetBeans IDE.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After searching for more than 5 hours , i got video for c++ and java you can see both videos and apply same logic for java - just check on java classes , because we need JAR file .
this are links to guide as how to make JAR file of Extra_module of face with base module of OpenCV.(needs Visual studio for it ).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fqpYLM6SCw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW5ARV21DN4

You can ask me for doubts if any , anytime - coz i dont want others to waste time on this like I did.
